# Weeks IN SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Below query creates weeks Sunday to Saturday

But I need weeks from Monday to Sunday

```
declare @begDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

set @begDate = '01-APR-2020'
set @endDate = '30-APR-2020';

WITH N(n) AS  
(   
    SELECT 0  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT n+1
    FROM N 
    WHERE n <= datepart(dd,@enddate)
)
SELECT      
    DATEADD(dd, n, @BegDate) AS dDate 
INTO
    #Noofweeks 
FROM        
    N
WHERE       
    MONTH(DATEADD(dd, n, @BegDate)) = MONTH(@BegDate)

SELECT 
    MIN(dDate) AS BegOfWeek,
    MAX(dDate) AS EndOfWeek,
    DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, dDate), 0)), 0), dDate) AS WeekNumForMonth
FROM
    #Noofweeks
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, dDate), 0)), 0), dDate) 
ORDER BY
    3, 1

DROP TABLE #Noofweeks
```

Comment: Why not use 7 days, instead of week for your day adds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej,

maybe try this

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
declare @begDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

set @begDate = '01-APR-2020'
set @endDate = '30-APR-2020';

WITH N(n) AS  
(   
 SELECT 0  
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT n+1
 FROM N 
 WHERE n <= datepart(dd,@enddate)
)
SELECT      
 DATEADD(dd, n, @BegDate) AS dDate 
INTO
 #Noofweeks 
FROM        
 N
WHERE       
 MONTH(DATEADD(dd, n, @BegDate)) = MONTH(@BegDate)


;WITH CTE 
AS
(SELECT  DISTINCT
DATEPART(WEEK, ddate)  -
 DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,ddate), 0))+ 1 AS WEEK_OF_MONTH,DATEPART(WEEK, ddate) as week_in_the_year  FROM #Noofweeks)

 SELECT cte.WEEK_OF_MONTH,n.begining_of_week,n.end_of_week FROM cte join 
 (SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, ddate) as week_in_the_year , MIN(ddate) as begining_of_week,MAX(ddate) end_of_week FROM #Noofweeks
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, ddate)) as n on cte.week_in_the_year= n.week_in_the_year


DROP TABLE #Noofweeks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the first day of the week:

```
DECLARE @datefirst int=@@DATEFIRST;
SET DATEFIRST 1;
--- Your code here
---
SET DATEFIRST @datefirst;
```